# How to store the character for each looping in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a string :

```
A="ILOVEYOUMATLAB"
```

and I create 2 empty array:

```
B1=[]
B2=[]
```

when i used the while loop, for the first time looping, if i want the first character from the **A** to store in **B1** array, what command i need to write?

if in Python, i just need to used **append** command, but if in Matlab, what is the commend need to apply?

Comment: you can write `B1 = [B1; A(1)]`

Answer (score 0):

If you have MATLAB R2016b or newer you can use the new [`string`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-string-arrays.html) class' overloaded `+` operator to append text in a more pythonic manner:

```
A = 'hi';
B = "";
B = B + A(1)
```

Which gives you:

```
B = 

    "h"
```

Here I've created `A` as a traditional character array (`''`) and `B` as a string array (`""`), mainly to avoid having to index into the string array (`A{1}(1)` instead of `A(1)`).

You can also just use traditional [matrix concatenation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html#f1-85019) to accomplish the task:

```
B = [B, A(1)];
% or
B = strcat(B, A(1));
% or
B(end+1) = A(1);
```

Note that 4 of these approaches will continually grow `B` in memory, which can be a significant performance bottleneck. If you know how many elements `B` is going to contain you can save a lot of IO time by [preallocating the array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html) and using matrix indexing to assign values inside your loop:

```
A = {'apple', 'banana', 'cucumber'};
B = char(zeros(1, numel(A)));

for ii = 1:numel(A)
    B(ii) = A{ii}(1);
end
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try **strcat** for concatenating strings in matlab
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html

Answer (score -1):

Try using arrays instead of matrices.  You can assign the first letter to the first position of the B1 array like this:

```
>> A = 'ILOVEMATLAB';
>> B1 = {};
>> B1{1} = A(1);
>> B1{1}

ans = 

I
```

To Loop through:

```
for i = 1:length(A)
    B1{i} = A{i};
end
```

Comment: This is not valid MATLAB syntax

Comment: I guess what @excaza meant was that A is a char array so it cannot be accessed with `{}`

Comment: Thanks! I was answering the OP that declared A to be a string. The code works for me though I'm not totally sure what is desired here...